# react - passing in a raw js array as a prop, but jsx is modifying it into a js object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Passing in a raw array as a prop, but it seems to be modified by React / jsx into a json object that has keys called "0", "1", etc, corresponding to the array elements.  This makes it impossible to be able to tell if the prop is actually an array or a single component.

For example,

MyComponent has:

```
   propTypes: {
      attachedComponents: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([React.PropTypes.array, React.PropTypes.object])
   }
```

Instantiate MyComponent and pass in an array:

```
   var foo = <Foo />  // my custom component 1
   var bar = <Bar />  // my custom component 2
   <MyComponent attachedComponents={[foo, bar]} />
```

**The problem, is that inside MyComponent, this.props.attachedComponents *is not a real JS array* -- it is some kind of JS Object that has keys "0", "1", each corresponding to the array element passed in.**

This nmakes it impossible for me to programatically determine if it was a single component that was passed in, or if it was an actual array, without doing some really bad kludging:

MyComponent:

```
   getInitialState: function() {
        // this cannot work as intended, because the array passed in is converted into a js object whose typeof is object, not array:
        if (typeof this.props.attachedComponents !== 'array') {
            // do code for single component situation
        }
    }
```

I cannot check on `Object.keys(this.props.attachedComponents).length`, since, for a single component passed in, `Object.keys(this.props.attachedComponents)` looks like this:

```
["$$typeof", "type", "key", "ref", "props", "_owner"]
```

Now, if you are wondering why I am passing in arrays of components, it is because I want to have programmatic addition of components; I have seen `this.props.children`, but this does not seem reliable at all:

> Facebook says that `this.props.children` is opaque, and you must use
>   React.Children api calls, all of which are getters, which seems to
>   imply that **`this.props.children` should not be mutated**.

Any ideas on how to detect if `this.props.attachedComponents` is an array, without doing some really bad kludging?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSX doesn't do anything to props.**

It's literally just syntactic sugar for calling `React.createElement`. [Your code gets converted to](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20foo%20%3D%20%3CFoo%20%2F%3E%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20my%20custom%20component%201%0Avar%20bar%20%3D%20%3CBar%20%2F%3E%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20my%20custom%20component%202%0A%3CMyComponent%20attachedComponents%3D%7B%5Bfoo%2C%20bar%5D%7D%20%2F%3E):

```
var foo = React.createElement(Foo, null); // my custom component 1
var bar = React.createElement(Bar, null); // my custom component 2
React.createElement(MyComponent, { attachedComponents: [foo, bar] });
```

---

Arrays **are** objects and `typeof` is weird. `typeof someArray` always returns `"object"`:

```js
console.log(typeof []);
```

The correct way to test for an array is to use `Array.isArray`:

```js
console.log(Array.isArray([]));
console.log(Array.isArray({}));
```

---

> I have seen `this.props.children`, but this does not seem reliable at all

Well, it is reliable, it just doesn't always return the same type of value. There are many helper functions available to process `this.props.children`. Have a look at [`React.Children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children). E.g. you can use `React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)` to convert the value to a true array.

The part you highlighted in the quote simple means that you shouldn't change the value of `this.props.children` itself. But that is not unreasonable in any way.

Comment: Thank you! I have been bitten by stupid JS things, and I think I made this error in the past too. There's just too many weird quirks to remember in JS for a full-stack to remember across 3-4  languages. Btw, I meant that this.props.children is not reliable in the sense that I am not confident I can properly mutate it, to programatically add / remove components. That's why I'm manually adding components as a array that I pass in as a prop.  This is probably better asked as another question (!)  Thanks!